# Remove Comments Metabox but still allow comments

Tags: functions, comments

I already know how to remove a metabox from my custom post type edit page.  However I want to remove the comments metabox but still allow commenting for the post.  Because I notice when I do remove it, it disables comments.  Any function I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't remove this via CSS. The _POST part is also active and WP save the data!
Use the hooks to remove meta boxes; code by scratch.

```
function fb_remove_comments_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv', 'post', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv', 'page', 'normal' );
    // remove trackbacks
    remove_meta_box( 'trackbacksdiv', 'post', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'trackbacksdiv', 'page', 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'fb_remove_comments_meta_boxes' );
```

see more on a plugin to remove all UI-elements and function for comments: https://github.com/bueltge/Remove-Comments-Absolutely

Comment: Please, notice that to disable the metabox for the CPT you need to write the CPT name instead of 'page' or 'post'. For instance, if your CPT is 'book' then it would be
remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv', 'book', 'normal' );

Answer (score 2):

You can use the UI to remove it:

Click on the "Screen Options" at the top right side of the edit screen

[image]

and uncheck the Discussion check box

[image]

or if you want to do it by code simply hide the container div by `style="display:none;"`

```
function hide_comments_div() {
global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow=='post-new.php' OR $pagenow=='post.php')
        echo '<style>#commentstatusdiv{ display:none; }</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_comments_div');
```

Comment: problem with this is that it doesn't remove it completely.  if you pull down the screen options you can recheck it and then it displays again.  I'm looking more for a way to force the comments to be allowed while I remove that metabox through the 'supports' option in the custom post type.

Comment: If you remove the comments through the 'supports' option in the custom post type you remove the comments all together. you can try using `remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv' , 'page' , 'normal' ); `

Answer (score 1):

There is problem in file `/wp-includes/post.php` function `wp_insert_post()`

```
if ( empty($comment_status) ) {
 if ( $update )
  $comment_status = 'closed';
 else
   $comment_status = get_option('default_comment_status');
}
```

Your comments will be close after update. The solution is change callback of commentstatusdiv insted:

```
add_action(
 'add_meta_boxes', function () {
    global $wp_meta_boxes, $current_screen;
    $wp_meta_boxes[$current_screen->id]['normal']['core']['commentstatusdiv']['callback'] = function () {
        global $post;
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $post->comment_status . '"      name="comment_status"/>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . $post->ping_status . '" name="ping_status"/>';
        echo '<style type="text/css">#commentstatusdiv {display: none;}</style>';
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `functions.php` of your theme

```
function tune_admin_area() {
        echo '<style>#commentstatusdiv{ display:none; }</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'tune_admin_area');
```

Comment: problem with this is that it doesn't remove it completely.  if you pull down the screen options you can recheck it and then it displays again.  I'm looking more for a way to force the comments to be allowed while I remove that metabox through the 'supports' option in the custom post type.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to hide some of the meta boxes, including the comment status box:

```
if (is_admin()) :
    function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
        if( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
            remove_meta_box('postcustom', 'post', 'normal');
            remove_meta_box('trackbacksdiv', 'post', 'normal');
            remove_meta_box('commentstatusdiv', 'post', 'normal');
            remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'post', 'normal');
        }
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );

    function handle_comments_setting( $data ) {
        if( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
            $data['comment_status'] = "open";
        }
        return $data;
    }
    add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'handle_comments_setting' );
endif;
```

This way the meta boxes will be hidden for all the contributors, but not the administrators.

In the second function `comment_status` is set to `"open"` only when the same conditions are met that caused the comments to be disabled in the first place.